# Convert Gatsby Website to WebFlow of WordPress?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, headless

The marketing manager of esper.io (built in gatsby) said that it's hard for them to do updates on the site (they need to contact the developer every time) so they're thinking about rebuilding the whole site in WebFlow or WordPress. The blog on site is headless WordPress.

I work mostly with WordPress and WebFlow and have zero experience with Gatsby or React.

I was wondering is there any simple way how to do updates on a Gatsby website so the marketing team can do it themselves? (they're non coders)

They love the headless WodPress blog because they're all familiar with WordPress and can write blog posts  without coding.

I'll appreciate any tips or pointing in  a direction.

Thank you, Josef

Answer (score 0):

I assume you still have a kind of deployment-process... means if you change something at the source-code and upload to your git-repository, the page will be rebuild and deployed automatically.

So if you search for an nice & easy way to edit the content of your page, I recommend to have a look at [TinaCMS](https://tina.io/)
It's also optimized for gatsby and - if ones integrated in gatsby - it's very easy to edit the content of the Page.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look.